# Issue with Click Element inside if statement in robot framework with ExtendedSelenium2Library

Tags: robotframework

I am using ExtendedSelenmium2Library but I got an error at click element that
**Keyword 'ExtendedSelenium2Library.Click Element' expected 1 to 2 arguments, got 0.**

```
run keyword if  '${HOLDER}' == '${SEARCH}'  
...     run keywords   
...     click element  xpath=.//*[@id='board']/div[${COUNT_A}]/div/div[1]/div/span
...     input text  xpath=.//*[@id='board']/div[${COUNT_A}]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/input  test123
```

Comment: Does the `Click Element` work outside of the `Run Keyword If` statement?

Comment: yes Click Element work outside if statement

Comment: What happens if you stuff those three keywords into your own made keyword? that way youre only calling one keyword instead of three different ones. if that makes sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[run keywords](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keywords) expects a list of keywords. In your statement, `run keywords` thinks that `click element` is the first keyword, `xpath=.//*[@id='board']/div[${COUNT_A}]/div/div[1]/div/span` *is the second keyword*, `input text` is the third keyword, and so on.

Thus, it sees that `click element` has no arguments so it throws an error stating that it got no arguments.

If you are trying to run keywords with arguments via `run keywords`, you must separate the keywords with `AND`

```
run keyword if  '${HOLDER}' == '${SEARCH}'  
...     run keywords   
...     click element  xpath=.//*[@id='board']/div[${COUNT_A}]/div/div[1]/div/span
...     AND  input text  xpath=.//*[@id='board']/div[${COUNT_A}]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/input  test123
```

From the documentation:

> By default all arguments are expected to be keywords to be executed.
>
> ...
>
> Starting from Robot Framework 2.7.6, keywords can also be run with arguments using upper case AND as a separator between keywords. The keywords are executed so that the first argument is the first keyword and proceeding arguments until the first AND are arguments to it. First argument after the first AND is the second keyword and proceeding arguments until the next AND are its arguments. And so on.